# Cron job to check for email, insert into database

Tags: php, email, cron

I would Like to have a cron job that would check for email to a certain address on the server it was running, and then insert the contents of that email onto a database depending on the subject etc.  as far as I am aware CRON jobs can be written in php, and the database part is not hard for me.  So then how would I go about check for a certain email??

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP imap email function will help you :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php